# Lazy load in iframe yotube videos

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

again I come to ask for help from you guys, I'm doing tests on the google page speed of my pages created with wordpress.

Before I was having problems with the images but through this script I managed to speed them up.

See the code:

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            const imageObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, imgObserver) => {
                entries.forEach((entry) => {
                    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                        const lazyImage = entry.target
                        console.log("lazy loading ", lazyImage)
                        lazyImage.src = lazyImage.dataset.src
                        lazyImage.classList.remove("lzy_img");
                        imgObserver.unobserve(lazyImage);
                    }
                })
            });
            const arr = document.querySelectorAll('img.lzy_img')
            arr.forEach((v) => {
                imageObserver.observe(v);
            })
        })
    </script>
```

Now I am having scoring problems with page speed because of the yotube videos.

Is there any script that can show videos or any YouTube iframe only if someone scrolls the page or clicks on it?

I would like the videos or any element using iframe on the pages to have a delay or something that can make the page faster.

Does anyone out there know anything that can do this?

I found this solution that seems perfect, but it only works if you edit all articles manually

Solution: https://github.com/groupboard/ytdefer

Would it be possible to apply this solution to all articles automatically?

Comment: You can use your code 1:1, just change `lazyImage` to reference the iframe(s)

Comment: I just pasted the subject of your post in google and got numerous results

Comment: Yes, I saw some suggestions on google but I already have many pages with videos from youtube and I would need a script that would do this job on all pages.

Comment: The suggestions I found are necessary to edit all the poses and add a class = to have the effect., I would need something more automatic that would do the job in the iframes